# Python: TypeError: unhashable type: 'Image'

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, screenshot, pyautogui

I am trying to create a bot for an MMO called "Graal Online Classic" with Pyautogui. It would read the "PM"(Personal Message) of a player who messages them, then reply with the appropriate response. It would also take a screenshot of the players name, store it in a dictionary(and also store where that particular player is in the bot's response hierarchy) and use that to determine if the player had messaged them before.

```
import time
import pyautogui

#option = None

def main():
    #find_notification()
    name_coords, reply_coords, text_coords = set_message_coords()
    option = read_message(text_coords)
    player_id(name_coords, option)
    answer = response()
    reply(reply_coords, answer)


def find_notification(): #looks for a waiting PM and clicks it
    while True:
        image = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('test.png', grayscale = False, confidence = .9)
        print(image)
        if image is not None:
            print('Found a waiting message')
            pyautogui.click(image)
            break


def set_message_coords(): # Creates coords for message box and screenshots name
    try:
        imagex, imagey = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('upper_right_message_corner.png', grayscale = True, confidence = .8)

    except:
        print('ERROR I SHOULD BE FINDING "upper_right_message_corner.PNG" EXITING PROGRAM') 
        exit()
    name_coords = (imagex - 424), imagey, 378, 50 # The coords of where the players name would be
    print('Found an open message')
    print(imagex, imagey)

    reply_coords = (imagex - 251), (imagey + 255 ) # Coords of the reply button
    text_coords = (imagex - 461), (imagey + 45), 430, 45 # Coords of where a players possible response is
    return name_coords, reply_coords, text_coords # Returns all coord values to be used by other functions


def player_id(name_coords, option): # Indentifies person who messaged and depending on if this person has messaged before changes response
    players = {} # Used to store players names and where in the response is

    name_image = pyautogui.screenshot('name_test.png', region = name_coords) # Names are screenshots 

    if name_image not in players:
        print("User was not previously found, adding to dictionary.")
        players[name_image] = None
    else:
        print("User is previous user.")
        players[name_image] = players[name_image] + option
        return players[name_image]


def reply(reply_coords, response): #Replies to PM
    pyautogui.click(reply_coords)
    pyautogui.typewrite(response)
    pyautogui.press('enter')


def read_message(text_coords): # Reads PM for numbers and sets option the number
    if pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('1.png',region = text_coords,  confidence = .9, grayscale = True):
        option = '1'
    elif pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('2.png',region = text_coords,  confidence = .9, grayscale = True):
        option = '2'
    elif pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('3.png',region = text_coords,  confidence = .9, grayscale = True):
        option = '3'
    elif pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('4.png',region = text_coords,  confidence = .9, grayscale = True):
        option = '4'
    elif pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('5.png',region = text_coords,  confidence = .9, grayscale = True):
        option = '5'
    elif pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('6.png',region = text_coords,  confidence = .9, grayscale = True):
        option = '6'
    elif pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('7.png',region = text_coords,  confidence = .9, grayscale = True):
        option = '7'
    elif pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('8.png',region = text_coords,  confidence = .9, grayscale = True):
        option = '8'
    elif pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('9.png',region = text_coords,  confidence = .9, grayscale = True):
        option = '9'
    elif pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('0.png',region = text_coords,  confidence = .9, grayscale = True):
        option = '0'
    else:
        print('ERROR CANT FIND DIGIT ANSWER')
        option = None
        #reply(reply_coords,'ERROR PLEASE ENTER A NUMBER RESPONSE!')
        #main()
    print(option)
    return option


def response(option): # All the possible responses the bot can give a player
    if option == None:
        return "Hello! I am bot made to answer your questions! PM the number for more options! 1: Bounties. 2: Bug Hunting. 3: Looting. 4: Farming."
    elif option == '1':
        return "The bounty quest allows you to hunt mobs for cash! Location: Castle, steward's room(to the right in the throne room) [PM 1 for specifics, PM 2 for TIPS, PM 3 for possible bounties]"
    elif option == '12':
        return '1. The bounty box will "drop"(stop following you, and will not pick up anything) after every kill/capture you get, and will require you to call it, or run over it to pick it up again. [PM 1 for more info, PM 9 to go back one level, PM 0 to reset choices]'
    elif option == '13':
        return '100 green blobs, 20 Lizardons, 75 Pyrats(as homage to the PQ I assume), 75 Rebel soldiers(regular green baddy), 60 dark blobs, 60 rats, 75 snakes, 75 bats, 75 bandits, 80 spiders, 50 archers, or 50 crabs. [PM 9 to go back one level, PM 0 to reset choices]'

main()
```

It produces the following error.

```
Found an open message
692 371
ERROR CANT FIND DIGIT ANSWER
None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Pablo\OneDrive\python_projects\chat_bot\main.py", line 104, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Pablo\OneDrive\python_projects\chat_bot\main.py", line 10, in main
    player_id(name_coords, option)
  File "C:\Users\Pablo\OneDrive\python_projects\chat_bot\main.py", line 47, in player_id
    if name_image not in players:
TypeError: unhashable type: 'Image'
[Finished in 1.9s]

Error happens in function player_id()
```

I do not have very much experience with list and dictionaries so I am uncertain how to deal with this. I have looked at similar threads with the error "TypeError: unhashable type:" but I do not really understand the responses. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: whetever returns from `pyautogui.screenshot` (in this case `name_image`) is not a hashable object so can't be used as a key in a dictionary.

Comment: Is there any way I can still use name_image in a dictionary? Or as a way to identify if name_image has messaged my bot before?

Comment: @OzgurVatansever

Comment: Even if it did work, how would you expect to add `option` to the initializing value of `None`? And I'm unfamiliar with pyautogui but something tells me that taking screenshots of messages on the screen is not a safe/reliable way of identifying users. Shouldn't you have access to some kind of underlying (text-based) events/messages?

Comment: @AndrasDeak Here's an image of a PM received in the game. http://i.imgur.com/JpzsxZ1.png You're right, using screenshots of names isn't the most reliable way to identify users, but it is really the only way I can think of identifying them. There is a clear name there, but some test with pytesseract have shown me that it's not the most reliable way of doing things.(That is why in read_message() I look for images instead of text). About adding option to None, None shouldn't be in option when we get to players[name_image] + option I was planning on having a number overwrite None before that point

Comment: `None` will not be in `option`, that's right. But `None` will be in `players[name_image]`. And then you'll effectively have `None + '1'` or something. `None + <anything>`. Also: don't you need to handle the `option` input in case of a new user? In which case you have to initialize with `option` and your `None` spontaneously goes away. As for the screenshots: where does the program know from that it got a PM? There has to be some underlying machinery that you can hook into. Those messages come from someplace, right?

Answer (score 0):

In order to add an item to a dictionary, it must be hashable. In most cases, this means it must be an immutable. You can't directly hash a `PIL.Image.Image()` object. Instead, you can create and store a `bytes` object and later retrieve that bytes object as follows:

```py
# Store the image
name_image = pyautogui.screenshot('name_test.png', region = name_coords) 
name_image_asbytes = name_image.tobytes()
players[name_image_asbytes] = None

# Retrieve data associated with the image
# In this case, I am using my_img as the image I want to get associated data from
data = players[my_img.tobytes()]

# Create image from bytes (in case you ever need to later on)
# You would also need to install the PIL library for this, but I suspect it is already installed because pyautogui needs PIL
# In this case, I am getting the image associated with the first player stored the "players" dictionary
from PIL.Image import Image
my_img = Image.frombytes(player.keys()[0])
# Do whatever you want with my_img
```